# Going from ARM NEON to Intel intrinsics for sum of absolute differences for a row of 8x uint8_t

Tags: c, x86-64, sse, intrinsics, neon

I am trying to convert some code using ARM NEON intrinsics to use Intel intrinsics instead.

I immediately got stuck and am trying to find the appropriate Intel intrinsics to replace the NEON intrinsics. My first hurdle is to translate the following function:

```
void sad_row_8(uint8_t *row1, uint8_t *row2, int *result)
{
    *result = 0;
    uint8x8_t vec1 = vld1_u8(row1);
    uint8x8_t vec2 = vld1_u8(row2);
    uint8x8_t absvec = vabd_u8(vec1, vec2);
    *result += vaddlv_u8(absvec);
}
```

In the code above, row1 and row2 are pointers to rows of at least 8 consecutive uin8_t elements. The function computes the sum of absolute differences between two rows of uint8_t elements.

When writing code using NEON intrinsics I used [https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D) to find appropriate intrinsics, and I never had much trouble finding what I needed.
In my attempt to find the correct Intel intrinsics to translate the code above, I have attempted using https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512&ig_expand=54,6050&cats=Load .
Here, I have tried to find corresponding intrinsics to the ones I have used in the NEON solution, but without much luck.

What I am looking for is help/advice on how I can better approach this problem, perhaps by pointing out some (possibly?) obvious flaws in my approach.

My processor is an Intel Core i5-11400F, which according to Intel has the instruction set extensions Intel® SSE4.1, Intel® SSE4.2, Intel® AVX2, Intel® AVX-512.

Comment: With AVX2, you could be doing four 8-byte SADs in parallel.  With 512-bit vectors, twice that.  But it's more efficient on contiguous data, so do 4 or 8 blocks in parallel, not 4 or 8 rows of the same block with strided loads, if you can.  That will also avoid horizontal sums; instead you can just vertically sum across the 8 rows of those blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Sum of absolute differences is done a bit differently in Intel.

In Neon programming one uses traditional per-lane `abd` operation and preferably *widening* accumulation - then a final horizontal reduction.

In Intel the intrinsic `_mm_sad_epu8` instead performs two abd+horizontal reductions in parallel:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 | 0 1 0 1 4 2 1 0 | < register A
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 | 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 | < register B
-----------------------------------
1 2 3 1 1 2 0 1   2 1 2 1 1 1 2 3   < -- Neon vabdq_u8(A,B)
11  (uint64_t)    13   (uint64_t)   < -- Intel _mm_sad_epu8(A,B)
```

The corresponding intel routine would be

```
void sad_row_8(uint8_t *row1, uint8_t *row2, int *result)
{
    *result = 0;
    __m128i vec1 = _mm_loadu_si64(row1);
    __m128i vec2 = _mm_loadu_si64(row2);
    __m128i absvec = _mm_sad_epu8(vec1, vec2);
    *result += _mm_cvtsi128_si32(absvec);
}
```

Comment: Note that in both arm and intel this method of accumulating just 8 bytes at a time is suboptimal.